# How to work with websockets in react js and spring boot application

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket, stompjs

I'm trying to connect with web socket which is on spring boot via React JS but not able to establish connection
I'm using the stompJS and sockjs-client libraries from npm
It's working while tested on local machine but when deployed on Ubuntu server it's not connecting
The front end and back end both are on same server

Here is the code for ReactJs

```
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import { over } from 'stompjs';

const connect = () => {
    const sock = new SockJS('/ws-endpoint');
    const temp = over(sock)
    setStompClient(temp);

    temp.connect({}, onConnected,onError)
}

const onError = (error) => {
    console.log('error: ', error);
}

const onConnected = (frame) => {
    console.log('frame: ', frame);
    console.log('Connected');
    setIsConnected(true);
}
const onMessageReceived = (payload) => {
    console.log('PayLoad:',payload.body);
    if(payload.body === 'REFRESH')  handleForceRerender();
}

useEffect(() => {
    connect();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if(isConnected && stompClient)  {
        const subscription = stompClient?.subscribe('/topic/notification', onMessageReceived)
        console.log('Subscribe called:');
        return () => {
            subscription?.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.